# Codeigniter не добавляются и не редактируются записи в БД

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, codeigniter

Имеется приложение написанное с помощью Codeigniter. При переносе с localhost на сервер появилась проблема: через некоторое время после авторизации пользователя в приложении(пока не получается поймать его закономерность) перестает работать добавление и редактирование записей, при чем удаление работает без проблем. Снова через некоторое время добавление и редактирование начинает работать, потом опять пропадает. На localhost  такого не было. На сервере лежит еще пара приложений, в которых нет подобных проблем. В логах проблем не обнаружено. На сервере MySQL 5.7.10, Apache 2.4.18, phpMyAdmin 4.5.3. Уже не знаю в какую сторону копать. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Иногда такое бывает, когда не хватает места на диске. База считается вместе со всеми файлами аккаунта на хостинге.

Comment: Свободного места еще 35ГБ, наверно этого достаточно

Comment: смотрите логи ошибок в базе данных, возможно некорректные данные заносятся в базу или превышение время выполнения запроса

Comment: где еще можно посмотреть логи к БД? Смотрю /var/log/apache2 и /var/log/mysql там всё норм

Comment: Конечно Вы это наверное первое проверяли, но может нету прав у Вас?)